# React functional component with <script> doesn't render script in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

Hey guys I have a component that renders google recaptcha script inside of it. It works in chrome and safari but not in firefox:

```
const MyHeaderComponent = (props)=>{

   return <head>
            <script type="application/javascript" src={`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=apikey`}></script>
         </head>
};
```

Anyone knows how to bypass this? I think firefox think it is malicious script and blocking it (the script) the component loads but with no script inside.

Comment: Does the component not render or does the script not load?

Comment: the script does not load @BrianThompson